# how can I save JSON?

Tags: node.js, nest

I can get posps from vk in JSON, but than I want to add these posts to postrgesQL. I can create resource for posts but how can I add these there and can I filter posts on backend?

```
request
```

```java
   @Injectable()
   export class AppService {
   
     private readonly logger = new Logger(AppService.name);
     constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}
   
     async findPost(): Promise<any> {
       const { data } = await firstValueFrom(
         this.httpService.get<any>('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-198838959&count=5&offset=10&access_token=08ed89a008ed89a008ed89a0f00bf82736008ed08ed89a06de41f5d7e95a7d62639387a&v=5.131').pipe(
             catchError((error: AxiosError) => {
               this.logger.error(error.response.data);
               throw 'An error happened!';
             }),
         ),
       );
       return data;
     }
   }
```

And I see:

[image]

Comment: I'd rather store JSON in NoSQL formats or convert to a relational structure,  but depends on what you intend to do with the data.

Comment: Postgres has very good [JSON support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-json.html), so you can store the whole document in a JSON column, if you like. You can even create indizes for the JSON column.
When your document is self-contained this can be a great choice. However, when the JSON has relations to other tables, then you may want to use the relational model, so that you can use foreign-keys, etc.

Comment: So, I need to understand how to do it).  User will send reaqest and this user will get posts.